# Git / detached HEAD, get work back?

Tags: git, bash, branch, zsh

I made a dozens of commits on what I thought was my branch, then checked out another branch.

Willing to go back to my initial branch, I didn't find my updated code. After looking at my history in console, I understood I worked in a detached branch...

Is it somehow possible to get the job I've done on the detached branch?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes. You can use the reflog. Try `git log -g HEAD`. This will show you the reflog for `HEAD`, i.e. every single commit that `HEAD` has pointed to, and the reason why it changed to that commit. You should be able to find your command that checked out the branch, and see what the previous commit was.

You can also use other syntax to index into the reflog. If you just performed the `git checkout branch`, then `HEAD@{1}` will refer to the previous checked-out commit (so you can `git checkout HEAD@{1}` to get back to it). Or if you know that 10 minutes ago `HEAD` was pointing to the right thing, you can use `git checkout HEAD@{10.minutes.ago}`.

Comment: @apneadiving: Anything you've actually committed to git can be retrieved later. It takes roughly 1.5 months before an unreferenced commit object is actually garbage collected (1 month to fall out of the reflog, and another 2 weeks before being deleted). Worst case you can find these objects with `git fsck --lost-found`.

Comment: I think you're off on the time frame: the default for gc.reflogExpire is 90 days, and the default for gc.pruneExpire is two weeks. But if I understand right, that's just the necessary age of an object to prune it. Once something in the reflog is older than 90 days, the objects it refers to are already older than two weeks, so both the reflog and the commit it refers to can be pruned immediately by the next `gc --auto` run.

Comment: @Jefromi: There's a separate timer for expiring unreachable objects from the reflog, which defaults to 30 days. And only once it becomes truly unreachable will `git gc` then unpack it from the pack, and *only then* will the 2 week timer start. It's not 2 weeks since the object was created, it's 2 weeks since the object became unpacked and loose on the filesystem (i.e. it's based on the modification date of the loose object in .git/objects/01/2345678...)

Comment: Thank you sooooo muuuuuch. If you were around, I would even kiss you (NO HOMO)

Answer (score 16):

Relax, everything is still there :)

Just call

```
git reflog
```

and `git` will tell you to what commits `HEAD` pointed before.  There will be a line like

```
checkout: moving from c70e36e25ac2dbedde6cb376719381fe0ab53f19 to master
```

telling you the SHA1 of the tip of your commits with a detached head.  Create a new branch pointing to that tip using

```
git branch saved-commits c70e36e25ac2dbedde6cb376719381fe0ab53f19
```

Now you can rebase that branch on top of the branch the commits were supposed to go to.