# How do I search git history for detached heads?

Tags: git

I accidentally added a commit to a detached HEAD state and then I checked out master again. I no longer have the commit hash, so I can't just check out the commit.  Instead, I am trying to search my git repo for all commits that I made in the last few days so that I can find it.  Is there a command to do this?

It looks like `git log --all` and `git rev-list --all` can only search from known refs.  Is there a way to do what I need or am I SOL?

Comment: Look up the `HEAD` reflog.

Comment: @Jubobs, you rock! Didn't know that command and it saved my ass. :) I used it and found the commit command in the history.  If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem, but your question is probably a duplicate, so I don't think I should post an answer.

Comment: Why not post an answer and if it is a dup, this question will be closed.  No harm done. I looked and couldn't find anything, but that was before I knew about the reflog command.

Comment: Ok, I may put something together, but tomorrow at the earliest. It's late, here :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git / detached HEAD, get work back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321145/git-detached-head-get-work-back)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `git reflog`. The reflog will list all movements of the HEAD, like checkouts, resets, rebases and commits. Therefore it should contain your missing commit.

Comment: @Jubobs already provided the answer in a comment. Waiting for him to promote comment to an answer.  If he doesn't make some noise and I'll accept your answer.